# Use BeautifulSoup to find partial text in a H tag inside a DIV class

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML inside DIV class content that looks like

```
<h2>
 <strong>
 Brookstone
 </strong>
 AS20194 Multi-functional Massage Chair
</h2>
```

My Python code is

```
soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'content'}).h2.text
```

And it returns

```
Brookstone
                         AS20194 Multi-functional Massage Chair
```

How should I update the codes so it returns

```
AS20194 Multi-functional Massage Chair
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclude unwanted tag on Beautifulsoup Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40760441/exclude-unwanted-tag-on-beautifulsoup-python)

Comment: No. The answer in that thread was to exclude strong but I was asking for to get the one that is not strong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to do `.extract()`, you can use `.find_next_sibling()` with parameter `text=True`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''<h2>
 <strong>
 Brookstone
 </strong>
 AS20194 Multi-functional Massage Chair
</h2>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

print(soup.h2.strong.find_next_sibling(text=True))
```

Prints:

```
 AS20194 Multi-functional Massage Chair
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really a master of Beautiful soup, but what I see is that it correctly returns the "text" part of the code. What you might want to try is see in the `bs4` documentation if there is a way to select content that is not formatted.

Comment: The Brookstone part is inside <strong> and I would like to get rid of that in the result. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `extract()` to ignore `strong` tag.you can try it:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html_doc="""<h2>
 <strong>
 Brookstone
 </strong>
 AS20194 Multi-functional Massage Chair
</h2>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')

for strong in soup.find("strong"):
    strong.extract()
print(soup.text)
```

Output will be:

```
AS20194 Multi-functional Massage Chair
```