# Conditional operators in Beautiful Soup findAll by attribute value

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to find all of `td`s that don't have a custom html attribute `data-stat="randomValue"` 
My data looks something like this:

```
<td data-stat="foo">10</td>
<td data-stat="bar">20</td>
<td data-stat="test">30</td>
<td data-stat="DUMMY"> </td>
```

I know that I can just select for `foo, bar, and test` but my actual dataset will have hunders of different values for `data-set` so it just wouldn't be feasible to code.

Is there something like a `!=` operator that I can use in beautiful soup? I tried doing:

```
[td.getText() for td in rows[i].findAll('td:not([data-stat="DUMMY"])')]
```

but I only get `[]` as a value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclude unwanted tag on Beautifulsoup Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40760441/exclude-unwanted-tag-on-beautifulsoup-python)

Comment: `.findall()` doesn't accept CSS selector syntax. Use `.select()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to filter out the unvanted tags, for example:

```py
print([td.text for td in soup.find_all("td") if td.get("data-stat") != "DUMMY"])
```

---

Or use CSS selector with `.select` (as @Barmar said in comments, `.find_all` doesn't accept CSS selectors):

```py
print([td.text for td in soup.select('td:not([data-stat="DUMMY"])')])
```

Comment: thanks! This works but what is the difference between the find all and select solutions?

Comment: @theloosygoose `.select` accepts CSS selectors, `.find_all` doesn't. The difference is only the API (for example, you can use `lambda` in `.find_all` etc.)